# spring - component autowired in one class but not in another

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I run into a strange problem where a `Component` injected with `@Autowire` is available in one class, but not in another one.

I use `@Autowired` in the attribute `network` of the classes `Account` and `Agreement`, but it is autowired only in the class `Agreement` but not in `Account`. The `@ComponentScan` runs over the 3 needed packages.

Here is the start class:

```
package com.ser.pm.tests;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.ser.pm.agreement, com.ser.pm.network, com.ser.pm.address")
public class zt_Agreement {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SignatureException, InterruptedException {

            ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(zt_Agreement.class, args);

            Agreement oagreement = ctx.getBean(Agreement.class);

            oagreement.SubmitAgreement();

    }
}
```

Here is the `Component` `Network` which has to be injected in the `Account`->`network` too

```
package com.ser.pm.network;

@Component
public class Network implements INetwork {

    public X2network xsnetwork;

    public Network() { xsnetwork = networkFactory.createnetwork(); }

    public boolean isBound() { return (xsnetwork != null); }

    public BigInteger getNumber(byte[] addr) { return xsnetwork.getNumber(addr); }

}
```

In this class the field `network` is not autowired:

```
package com.ser.pm.address;

@Component
public class Account implements IFSAccount {

    @Autowired
    Network network;

    public Account(String ir_Address, String ir_Name) {}

    public Account() {}


    public BigInteger getNumber() {
        return network.getNumber(Hex.decode(this.getAddress()));
    }

}
```

In this class the field `network` is autowired correctly

```
package com.ser.pm.agreement;

@Component
public class Agreement {

    protected Account oFSEthAddress;

    private Trans oTx;

    private AgreementABI oABIs;

    @Autowired
    Network network;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public Agreement() {
        oFSEthAddress        = new Account();
        oagreementAccountOil = new FSEthagreementAccount();

    }


    public Trans JoinAgreement(String iPrivateKey) throws FScx {

        FSNetGas oFSEthNetGas = new FSNetGas();

        oFSEthAddress.setEtherum(oNetwork.onetwork);

        SCTrans oFSTx = new FSTrans();

        oFSTx.createCallTrans(_oTxParams);
        oFSTx.submit(oNetwork.onetwork);

        return oFSTx.getTrans();

    }

}
```

The classes `Account` and `Agreement` are in different packages but both of them are scanned with `@ComponentScan`, therefore I don't understand why I have problems with the autowiring in the class `Account`?

Comment: You are creating a new instance yourself in the constructor... That instance isn't managed by spring and as such won't receive any dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using spring to obtain Account instance - so spring did not get a chance to autowire it.this line :

```
oFSEthAddress        = new Account();
```

Comment: but if I mark the class Account with @Component, then Spring should create a bean object, or am I wrong?

Comment: if spring creates the bean, it will autowire the dependency. However you have created using new operator- so this bean is not managed by spring container - spring cannot autowire it

Comment: that means, that I have created one bean which Spring doesn't know about it. But Spring still have to create another Bean because the class Account is annotated with @Component, right? Or Spring doesn't create beans if an object of the class has already created? Sorry for the newbie question

Comment: spring scopes - singleton,prototype... are different. In your case - the class has the @Component annotation - but only if you request spring an instance of it - spring can autowire the dependency. Since you created new instance directly spring does not know a new instance of the class got created.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will change the code and I will come up to you again, but I think that you are right. By the way, is there a way to detect this kind of issues in my project? or do I have to search over all the source code for the statement that you noticed **new Account();**

Comment: Hi Balaji, thanks a lot, it works! Is there a way to detect this kind of issues in my project? or do I have to search over all the source code for the statement that you noticed new Account();

Comment: not sure about any tools/plugin that does this for us. have a look at spring tool suite - easiest way to get started for spring based projects